# Pass selected attributes to post request from form

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I've got a form with a dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="departments">Dept. Code</form:label>
    <form:select path="departments" items="${departmentMap}" multiple="true" />
```

`departmentMap` comes from the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeForm", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView showOfficeForm() {
    ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("officeForm", "command", new Office());
    List<Department> departmentsToDisplay = departmentServiceImpl.findAll();
    Map<Department, String> departmentMap = new HashMap<Department, String>();
    for (Department d : departmentsToDisplay) {
        departmentMap.put(d, d.getDepartmentName());
    }

    result.addObject("departmentMap", departmentMap);
            return result;
}
```

POST method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addOffice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateOffice(@ModelAttribute("office") Office office, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println("Office Name: " + office.getOfficeName());
        System.out.println("Departments: " + office.getDepartments());


         return new ModelAndView("result", "command", office);
    }
```

Excerpt from Office.java:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "offices")
    private List<Department> departments;
```

Excerpt from Department.java:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="OFF_DEPT_T",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="OFF_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
        )
    private List<Office> offices = new ArrayList<Office>();
```

If I print the response.getAllErrors() I get:

```
Field error in object 'office' on field 'departments': rejected value [package.domain.Department@5597e5cf,package.domain.Department@2d14d0a7]; codes [typeMismatch.office.departments,typeMismatch.departments,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [office.departments,departments]; arguments []; default message [departments]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'departments'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [package.domain.Department] for property 'departments[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Can anybody show me how to pass the object but display the String?  Thanks.

Comment: Show your POST method code.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, POST method added.

Comment: What about your Office class?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, I added the association code between Office and Department.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, please see my latest updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bound command to a new office attribute.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/officeSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String showOfficesSearch(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", new Office());
    return "officeSearch";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Problem 1:***

As you are missing initialisation of List `departments`. You should initialise it before putting it in model by replacing:

```
  ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("officeForm", "command", new Office());
```

with:

```
  Office office = new Office():
  office.setDepartments(new ArrayList<Department>()):
  ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("officeForm", "command", office);
```

Or if you don't want initialisation in controller, you can initialise it at the time of creation of `Office` object, like below:

```
  private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();
```

***Problem 2:***

As you want to bind custom object (Department) list in your `select` path, you need to provide a custom Property Editor to the data binder, like below:

First create a Property Editor class, something like this:

```
public class DepartmentEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       Department department = new department();
       department.setName(text);
       setValue(department);
    }
}
```

Then register the property Editor by registering it. You can register it, by simply putting an `initBinder` method in your controller class like below:

```
 @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(Department.class, new DepartmentEditor());
 }
```

Now, your code should work fine.

Comment: This got me a step further but please see my comments.  I'm passing the string that's being displayed instead of the object.  It's still not saving.

Comment: @JoeEssey, Please see my edit. Sorry for being late for the weekend trip... :P